# Defining a dot operator at the baseline

Tags: math-operators

I want to define an operator which uses the '.' symbol on the margin, with proper spacing. Simply using a period doesn't give the right spacing around the arguments. Usually I use `\mathop` for this sort of thing, but `\mathop{.}` gives the same result as if I used `\cdot`, that is, places the dot in the centre! Is there anyway I can do this?

Comment: What do you mean by “on the margin”? Should it behave like a binary operation? Note that `\mathop` is for symbols such as `\sum` or `\sin`, not for operations.

Comment: @egreg I know what's wrong -- I confused `\mathop` with `\mathbin`! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confused `\mathop` with `\mathbin`. What I want can be achieved by doing `a \mathbin{.} b`.